# JPanel getWidth() returns Zero, after invoking pack()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I believe my code will describe what I wrote, But the problem is, is that When I run it, I get that infamous "Exception in thread "Animator" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0" Error. I have searched for answers but have yet to find why this is happening.

```
package com.shparki.TowerDefense;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

//==================== PROGRAM VARIABLES ====================//
    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private static final int SCALE = 4;

    private static final int TARGET_FPS = 45;
    private static final int PERIOD = 1000 / TARGET_FPS;

    private boolean debug = true;
    private volatile boolean running = false;
    private volatile boolean gameOver = false;
    private volatile boolean paused = false;

    private Thread animator;
    private TowerDefense frame;

    private double currentFPS;


//==================== PROGRAM METHODS ====================//
    public GamePanel(TowerDefense td){
        frame = td;

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void addNotify(){
        super.addNotify();
        startGame();
    }
    public void startGame(){
        if (!running && animator == null){
            animator = new Thread(this, "Animator");
            animator.start();
        }
    }
    public void stopGame(){
        running = false;
    }
    public void run(){
        running = true;
        Long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleepTime;

        while(running){
            beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            update();
            render();
            paintScreen();

            timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
            sleepTime = PERIOD - timeDiff;
            if (sleepTime <= 0){
                sleepTime = 5L;
            }

            currentFPS = (1000 / ( timeDiff + sleepTime ));

            try{
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

//==================== DRAWING METHODS ====================//
    private Graphics dbg;
    private Image dbImage;

    public void paintComponenet(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (dbImage != null){
            g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
    public void paintScreen(){
        Graphics g;
        try{
            g = this.getGraphics();
            if (g != null & dbImage != null){
                g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            g.dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("Graphics context error: " + ex); }
    }
    public void doubleBuffer(){
        if (dbImage == null){
            dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
            if (dbImage == null){
                System.out.println("dbImage is null");
                return;
            } else {
                dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
            }
        }
    }

//==================== UPDATE METHODS ====================//
    public void update(){

    }


//==================== RENDER METHODS ====================//
    public void render(){
        doubleBuffer();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) dbg;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

}
```

And this is my frame class:

```
package com.shparki.TowerDefense;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TowerDefense extends JFrame implements WindowListener{

    public TowerDefense(String name){
        super(name);
        setResizable(false);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new GamePanel(this), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }


    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {  }
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {  }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {  }
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {  }
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {  }
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {  }
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {  }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TowerDefense("Tower Defense Game");
    }

}
```

Comment: Just as a comment, Swing components are already double buffered and using `this.getGraphics` is highly unrecommended as it can produce undesirable effects and paint problems...

Comment: Just as another Comment: You should try and [avoid tweaking the sizing hints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) i.e. setXXsize

Comment: Thanks for the input! As you can tell I am just learning Graphics Programming, and most of what I know so far comes for "Killer Java Game Programming".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JFrame` has not been packed then the height and widths are requested here in `GamePanel`

```
dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
```

resulting in `0x0` dimension for the `JPanel`.

The reason is that Swing invokes [addNotify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#addNotify%28%29) (where `startGame` resides) almost immediately once the parent component has been set for the component.

You could invoke `startGame` explicitly after pack has been called.

```
add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
pack();
gamePanel.startGame();
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my code so that I use a method getPWidth() & getPHeight() rather than the default so that it works.